# No audio on HP laptop 840 G6 with Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, sound

My [HP EliteBook 840 G6 laptop](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-elitebook-840-g6-notebook-pc/26609796) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS has no sound output. I tried all the possible solutions given here:

https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/06/fix-no-sound-dummy-output-issue-in.html

http://askubuntu.com/questions/873881/how-to-install-bang-and-olufsen-audio-drivers-for-hp-laptop

But i do not have file under /dev/snd like hwC0D0

> Terminal:~$ hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_COEF_INDEX 0x67 open: No such file or directory
>
> Terminal:~$ hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC0D0 0x20 SET_PROC_COEF 0x3000 open: No such file or directory

How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 and right version of laptop is 840 G6 model.

Comment: I have the same problem with Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: same with arch linux... nothing under /dev/snd

Comment: I installed Windows then update my bios using HP support assistance. Then i installed Ubuntu that helped me to fix this issue.