# Sound card not detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - sof-audio-pci

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, alsa

After installing Ubuntu 20.04, I noticed that sound is not working on my system.

`aplay -l` was giving me `Sound card not detected` error.

Running `inxi -A | grep driver` gave me `... driver: sof-audio-pci`

I tried some solutions on AskUbuntu, but they did not work and all of them used driver `snd_hda_intel`. Other pages said that firmwares for this driver are not shipped with distribution.

Is it possible to make sound work for Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As I said the sound driver I was running was `sof-audio-pci`, which had no normal firmware at the moment.

I searched nearly 3 hours trying to solve this headache and finally found the solution, just disable this "sof" driver and fall back to intel:

Do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and **Reboot**.

You can check if soundcards are detected with:

```
aplay -l
```

[Source](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=48&t=311714&sid=66ec8353cda692d136d028b2ae3d977c&start=20)

Comment: Excellent!!!! After spending hours with hunting down my 'no sound' problem, this did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: Although this answer fixed my audio, it disabled my microphone. For a more holistic solution, see my answer below.

Comment: `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` is now deprecated. What fixed the problem for me was `snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver`. The value `=3`, using SOF driver, was the right one for me to get speakers+headphones+microphone working.

Answer (score 12):

I had a similar problem on Arch Linux on a Lenovo Thinkpad X13 with kernel version 5.10. The solution is "similar" to @Olimjon, but I changed another kernel module parameter. Indeed, `modinfo snd_hda_intel` states that:

```
parm:           dmic_detect:Allow DSP driver selection (bypass this driver) (0=off, 1=on) (default=1); deprecated, use snd-intel-dspcfg.dsp_driver option instead (bool)
```

Running `modinfo snd_intel_dspcfg` gives the following info:

```
parm:           dsp_driver:Force the DSP driver for Intel DSP (0=auto, 1=legacy, 2=SST, 3=SOF) (int)
```

So I added `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` to my `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to get the same effect. The other values give me no audio.

Also, you should note that both solutions break the internal microphone.

Comment: Worked for me on Debian Testing (kernel 5.15) and Tiger Lake!

Comment: How do you "not break" the internal microphone and still have a solution?

Comment: See my answer below for a solution that doesn’t break your microphone.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is only a temporary solution, as after implementing it, my microphone no longer worked.

A more permanent solution would be to install the SOF firmware binaries from here: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

Specifically:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git`
2. Change to directory: `cd sof-bin`
3. Follow: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin#install-process-with-installsh

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2
```

4. Reboot

After this the sound output as well as the microphone were working (Ubuntu 23.04, Lenovo X1 Gen8)

Note: Make sure that the `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` settings are not set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

Comment: @Votti thanks a lot for the extra steps! Very helpful.

Comment: how to tell which version should be attempted?

Comment: @con why not use the latest release? https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/releases/tag/v2.2.6

Comment: version 2.2.x seems to work the best, i.e. my headphones work, but speakers don't

Comment: @con, did you make sure that the `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` settings are not set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`?

Comment: yes, I made sure that neither the bash variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` nor snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect are set in /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf my question is @ https://askubuntu.com/questions/1479661/new-22-04-install-cannot-play-sound-on-speakers

Comment: Not fully working for me on HP Dragonfly 13.5 inch G4 Notebook PC with Linux 6.4.6-3-rt8-MANJARO. I got some sound out of the speakers but not very low and certainly not using the different speakers of the computers.

Comment: @cmbarbu can you try the suggestions listed [here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Audio/No-sound-from-internal-speakers-using-Linux/m-p/8478057/highlight/true#M119011) and see if they work?

Comment: @cmbarbu did any of the suggestions work? If so, could you please add an answer to this question so that others know about a solution?