# No sound on Ubuntu 20.04, Lenovo Thinkbook 14s G2

Tags: 20.04, sound, lenovo

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and everything, aside from the sound, works flawlessly. The weird thing is that when the audio is triggered (by a system sound, muting/unmuting) there's a weird bleep (sounds like something being deflated). And when on wired headphones, there's only static. Bluetooth headphones work I guess because it's another interface?

I've tried upgrading the kernel, I also looked into some other similar questions, but it seems this is something different.

---

Here's the output for `sudo lshw -C multimedia` @sancho.s

```
  *-usb:0                   
       description: Video
       product: Integrated Camera
       vendor: SunplusIT Inc
       physical id: 5
       bus info: usb@3:5
       version: 56.14
       capabilities: usb-2.01
       configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
  *-multimedia
       description: Multimedia audio controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
       version: 20
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=sof-audio-pci latency=64
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:600-5ff irq:165 memory:601d180000-601d183fff memory:601d000000-601d0fffff
```

And here's the output for the other commands @sancho

`$ cat /proc/asound/cards`

```
0 [sofhdadsp      ]: sof-hda-dsp - sof-hda-dsp
                     LENOVO-20VA-ThinkBook14sG2ITL-LNVNB161216
```

`$ lsmod | grep snd`

```
snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp    28672  5
snd_soc_hdac_hdmi      36864  1 snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     65536  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   139264  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    86016  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_soc_dmic           16384  1
snd_sof_pci            24576  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    94208  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_soc_hdac_hda       24576  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_hda      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_sof_intel_byt      28672  1 snd_sof_pci
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               131072  4 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_hda_ext_core       32768  4 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    49152  2 snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_soc_acpi           16384  3 snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_intel_byt
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_sof
snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_pci,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
soundwire_intel        40960  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_intel_dspcfg
snd_hda_codec         147456  6 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hda_core           94208  11 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_soc_core          290816  7 soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_soc_dmic,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp
snd_compress           28672  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm               118784  12 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_sof_intel_ipc,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                73728  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              40960  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    94208  25 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_soc_hdac_hdmi,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp,snd_rawmidi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
```

`$ dpkg -L linux-modules-5.11.0-051100-generic | grep snd`

https://pastebin.com/yM4W9bin

`$ inxi -SA`

(inxi not installed)

`$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 4 Audio`

(empty)

`$ uname -a`

```
Linux camila 5.11.0-051100-generic #202102142330 SMP Sun Feb 14 23:33:21 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`$ aplay -l`

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 0: HDA Analog (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 1: HDA Digital (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 3: HDMI1 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 4: HDMI2 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: sofhdadsp [sof-hda-dsp], device 5: HDMI3 (*) []
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

`$ dpkg -l | grep alsa`

```
ii  alsa-base                                  1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5                  all          ALSA driver configuration files
ii  alsa-topology-conf                         1.2.2-1                               all          ALSA topology configuration files
ii  alsa-ucm-conf                              1.2.2-1ubuntu0.5                      all          ALSA Use Case Manager configuration files
ii  alsa-utils                                 1.2.2-1ubuntu2                        amd64        Utilities for configuring and using ALSA
ii  gstreamer1.0-alsa:amd64                    1.16.2-4                              amd64        GStreamer plugin for ALSA
```

`$ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
```

Comment: Have you tried [the options outlined in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1165640/1091774)? 

Comment: @Matigo I just tried that, nothing changed.

Comment: Check if https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul or the answers there help

Comment: As a first step, install `linux-modules-<kernel version>-generic` and `linux-modules-extra-<kernel version>-generic`.

Comment: You can try installing `pavucontrol` package and playing around with it to see if it displays anything useful pointing out the problem.

Comment: Hi @rsoto, have you find the solution? I've the same problem but it seems it happens only when I restart windows and enter ubuntu, but it is fixed once I turn off the laptop, and then turn it on again (not restart) and enter ubuntu.

Comment: Why not showing us your hardware? Please [edit] and copy/paste the output of `sudo lshw -C multimedia` and poke me

Comment: I would also check in Ubuntu Settings/Sound if output device is properly set. There may be more than one sound device, and Ubuntu sets the wrong one as default.

Comment: @cmak.fr I've updated the output for that command.

Comment: @qba-dev there's only one sound device, so no luck there.

Comment: Make sure the sound driver is installed correctly on Ubuntu 20.04. It might help. What computers are not affected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the driver you are using is `sof-audio-pci`.
As per [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1243370/226614), you may try with `snd_hda_intel`.
Simply copying the procedure:

1. Edit grub

   ```
   $ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Change

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   ```

   to

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
   ```
3. Update grub

   ```
   $ sudo update-grub
   ```
4. Reboot

You can check if soundcards are detected with

```
$ aplay -l
```

If that doesn't work, it may help if you post the output of:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
$ lsmod | grep snd
$ dpkg -L linux-modules-<kernel version>-generic | grep snd
$ inxi -SA
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A 4 Audio
$ uname -a
$ aplay -l
$ dpkg -l | grep alsa
$ grep intel /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

**Related**

1. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=253588
2. [Only "Dummy output" (sound) in Ubuntu 20.04 after reboot - Broken driver / module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1258510/only-dummy-output-sound-in-ubuntu-20-04-after-reboot-broken-driver-modul)

Comment: So, I'm not sure what happened, but I updated grup as instructed, then I rebooted and sound output was still not working, but not only that, input was not even showing as a recognized device. So I edited grub again to rollback changes and start running those commands, and then I tried rebooting but got a black screen for 3 mins or so, so I forced a shutdown and when I got back the sound was working!

Comment: @rsoto - So now you have everything working as it should? What is now left in your grub line? Which driver are you using now (`sudo lshw -C multimedia`)?
It is good that you take a few minutes to provide feedback, for the benefit of the community.

Comment: sure, I'll be updating the question with the output for those commands. The grub line is as it was originally, with `quiet splash`

Comment: @rsoto you accepted the answer, has it been solved?

Comment: @fikr4n yes, it has.