# 22.04 LTS No sound - Intel sound card snd_hda_intel not working

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04

```
$ aplay -l
**** Lista de PLAYBACK dispositivos hardware ****
tarjeta 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], dispositivo 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdispositivos: 1/1
  Subdispositivo #0: subdevice #0

$ cat /proc/asound/modules
 0 snd_hda_intel

$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Subsystem: QUANTA Computer Inc Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 16
    Memory at b121c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at b1000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_cnl

##grub##
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="loglevel=3 snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
```

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to install the SOF firmware binaries from here: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

Specifically:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git`
2. Change to directory: `cd sof-bin`
3. Follow: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin#install-process-with-installsh (for me v2.2 worked)

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2
```

4. Reboot

After this the sound output as well as the microphone were working (Ubuntu 23.04, Lenovo X1 Gen8)

Note: Make sure that the `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` settings are not set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Otherwise the sound may work but no microphone input.

Related question/answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/142531

Answer (score 0):

in my case the kernel driver was using the snd_sof one instead of the snd_hda_intel one, but maybe this fix will also work for you.

try adding this to the alsa-base.conf:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
```

and of course reboot afterwards

Comment: Having exact same problem, this did not fix it

Comment: This fixed sound issue for me, but this option disables mic detection completely. Not a good solution.

Comment: I had an issue (on PopOS, Lenovo X1 9th Gen) where output sound worked, but didn't find the mic/input device. When I _removed_ this line, the mic started working.