# 22.10 microphone not working

Tags: sound, microphone, 20.10

My laptop microfone works when trying ubuntu 22.10 in live mode from a USB, but after installing the OS, only "Digital Microphone - Family 17h/19h HD Audi..." is listed in the sound settings and no application can record anything. In windows (I have dual boot) the mic works perfectly. Also, running/installing the 23.04 daily build leads to a perfectly fine working mic, though due to other hickups I wanted to change to a stable version.

I have tried installing minimal+proprietary drivers and "normal" Version of the OS, same result.
I have also tried every single solution mentioned on following sites:

1. https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=352677 (modifying the alsa-base.conf file with `options snd_hda_intel model=inv-dmic`)
2. [Headset microphone not working on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1230016/headset-microphone-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04) (followed up from 1., tried only those solutions not dealing with codec entries in `also-base.conf`, because I could not find my codec on kernel.org, ouput of `cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec` was `Nvidia GPU a0 HDMI/DP`, `ATI R6xx HDMI`, and `Realtek ALC257`. Also, using `hdajackretask` shows Black Mic, Right side, as well as Internal Mic as options)
3. [Problem with sound in Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436904/problem-with-sound-in-ubuntu-22-10) (doing anything like activating pulseaudio as adviced here leads to audio output also misbehaving, but since they try to solve errors with audio output and not input, I didn't really except these solutions to work)
4. https://gist.github.com/Therises/d2e91c81af1574f9069635d520fdc7ec (this lead to the mic-icon to appear in the quick-settings drop-down menu, and in settings the indicator of input level is not constantly full anymore, so that is some progress I think)

After each unsuccessful attempt I reversed the changes and rebooted the system.

So... Anybody got some more ideas? I am really starting to get annoyed after almost half a dozen hours of trouble shooting...