# No Audio after Booting into Windows or Switching Desktops

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, pipewire

I'm running an Asus Zenbook 14, that I use to dual-boot between Windows and Ubuntu Unity (though since I like trying out other desktops I tend to also have a revolving door of other ones I like to try like KDE, XFCE, and LXDE)

My issue is, whenever I either boot into Windows and then back into Ubuntu, or even when I switch desktops, either away from or back into Unity, I find that my audio stops working, and I [can only see the Family 17h Audio Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH3G6.png) .

I think I had this problem when I first installed Ubuntu Unity, but after messing around with various potential fixes:

[Problem with sound in Ubuntu 22.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1436904/problem-with-sound-in-ubuntu-22-10)

[No sound output devices listed after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1403665/no-sound-output-devices-listed-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

[ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)

...disabling Fast Boot in both Windows and the BIOS was the solution, at least initially.

Ideally I'd like to have a solution that I can maybe implement into a startup shell that would automatically run and preemptively kickstart the sound every time I boot so that I don't have to deal with this problem every time I boot back into Ubuntu from Windows or change desktops.