# 22.04 LTS No sound - Intel sound card snd_hda_intel not recognized

Tags: drivers, sound, 22.04

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my laptop and while everything works great, I have no sound on my computer.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Raven/Raven2 Root Complex
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx
    Flags: fast devsel

03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Raven/Raven2/Fenghuang HDMI/DP Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at fe7c8000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 10h-1fh) HD Audio Controller
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Pavilion Laptop 15-cw1xxx
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49, IOMMU group 10
    Memory at fe7c0000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [48] Vendor Specific Information: Len=08 <?>
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [64] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [100] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=010 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
```

Comment: Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community. Your question as written is unclear. Can you please provide some additional context around what it is that you're doing and what you hope to achieve? This will help us better address your issue. For example, what brand/model of computer do you have (this will help others if they have the same problem)? Had you been running previous versions of Ubuntu (or any other OS) on this machine?

Comment: Some possible solutions given the information currently available. Please review the following discussions here on this site and let us know if these might be applicable solutions: - https://askubuntu.com/q/1421513/32664
- https://askubuntu.com/q/1225463/32664 There are ~500 such question discussions here on this Ask Ubuntu site alone, so this appears to be a common issue (without knowing hardware specifics).

Comment: What happens if you open a terminal and enter `sudo modprobe -r snd_hda_intel && sudo modprobe snd_hda_intel` please?
`

Comment: When I put the command you told me in the terminal, the following appears: `modprobe: FATAL: Module snd_hda_intel is in use.`

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to install the latest Sound Open Firmware (SOF) binaries from here: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin

Specifically:

1. Clone the repository: `git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin.git`
2. Change to directory: `cd sof-bin`
3. Follow: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin#install-process-with-installsh (for me v2.2 worked)

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2
```

4. Reboot

After this the sound output as well as the microphone were working (Ubuntu 23.04, Lenovo X1 Gen8)

Note: Make sure that the `snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0` or `snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1` settings are not set in `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` or `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`. Otherwise the sound output may work but no microphone input.

Related question/answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/142531