# No sound from Intel HD Audio (built in) in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pipewire

### Description

I have a [ROG STRIX B760-F Gaming](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-b760-f-gaming-wifi-model/) Motherboard and I specifically want to use the optical output of the internal soundcard in Ubuntu 22.04. The issue is that I get no sound at all, not via the optical out or via any of the analog outputs (like speaker). In my audio settings I can select from:

- HDMI/Displayport - HDA Nvidia,
- Digital Output (S/PDIF) U22 XT USB
- Analogue Output U22 XT USB
- Digital Output (S/PDIF) - USB Audio

where the [U22 XT](https://www.esi-audio.com/products/u22xt/) is just a USB card that I use for recording sometimes (which works fine, but I want to be able to use the built-in audio as well). The last option seems to be the one from the motherboard, since if I connect anything to the analog jacks, it changes to 'Speaker' etc. So yes, it reacts to connections, but no sound whatsoever. But I don't know why it's called 'USB' since it's built in (?).

Any help would be much appreciated!

### I have tried:

- I have tested that this works in Windows 10, so there isn't anything wrong with the hardware or cables.
- I have restarted pulseaudio:

```
pulseaudio --kill
pulseaudio --start
```

- Set and restart Pipewire

```
sudo touch /usr/share/pipewire/media-session.d/with-pulseaudio
systemctl --user restart pipewire-session-manager
```

- The command `lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel` gives:

```
snd_hda_intel          61440  5
snd_intel_dspcfg       32768  3 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         212992  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_hda_core          147456  7 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               196608  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   143360  41 snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_usb_audio,snd_usbmidi_lib,snd_hda_codec,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_ump,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

so I tried (following advice from [here](https://devicetests.com/fixing-audio-output-issue-ubuntu)):

```
echo "options snd-hda-intel model=generic" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf
```

- I also tried completely removing and installing alsa-base and pulseaudio:

```
sudo apt remove --purge alsa-base
sudo apt remove --purge pulseaudio
sudo apt install alsa-base pulseaudio
```

and

```
sudo alsa force-reload
```

Update:

- I have now also tried installing the [SOF firmware binaries](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin) as explained in an answer to [a related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1421513/22-04-lts-no-sound-intel-sound-card-snd-hda-intel-not-working).

I installed v2.2 using manual installation instructions on github and I also tried the [latest release](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/releases/tag/v2023.12) using the install.sh script. None of them worked.

- I have now also tried changing
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to
  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"`

(also tried with =3) in `/etc/default/grub`, and running:
`sudo update-grub` afterwards, then reboot. None of this worked.

### Additional info

Ubuntu 22.04.4

Kernel: 6.5.0-18-generic

Output of `lspci -v` for the intel audio device:

```
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 7a50 (rev 11)
    DeviceName: Intel HD Audio
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 8882
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 236
    Memory at 4002220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 4002000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

Output of `aplay -l`:

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 1: USB [U22 XT USB], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 2: USB Audio [USB Audio #2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 3: Audio [USB Audio], device 3: USB Audio [USB Audio #3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Here is my alsa config: `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
# autoloader aliases
install sound-slot-0 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-0
install sound-slot-1 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-1
install sound-slot-2 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-2
install sound-slot-3 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-3
install sound-slot-4 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-4
install sound-slot-5 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-5
install sound-slot-6 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-6
install sound-slot-7 /sbin/modprobe snd-card-7

# Cause optional modules to be loaded above generic modules
install snd /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-ioctl32 ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }
#
# Workaround at bug #499695 (reverted in Ubuntu see LP #319505)
install snd-pcm /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-pcm $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-pcm-oss ; : ; }
install snd-mixer /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-mixer $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-mixer-oss ; : ; }
install snd-seq /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-seq $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-oss ; : ; }
#
install snd-rawmidi /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-rawmidi $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq-midi ; : ; }
# Cause optional modules to be loaded above sound card driver modules
install snd-emu10k1 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-emu10k1 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-emu10k1-synth ; }
install snd-via82xx /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install snd-via82xx $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist snd-seq ; }

# Load saa7134-alsa instead of saa7134 (which gets dragged in by it anyway)
install saa7134 /sbin/modprobe --ignore-install saa7134 $CMDLINE_OPTS && { /sbin/modprobe --quiet --use-blacklist saa7134-alsa ; : ; }
# Prevent abnormal drivers from grabbing index 0
options bt87x index=-2
options cx88_alsa index=-2
options saa7134-alsa index=-2
options snd-atiixp-modem index=-2
options snd-intel8x0m index=-2
options snd-via82xx-modem index=-2
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-usb-caiaq index=-2
options snd-usb-ua101 index=-2
options snd-usb-us122l index=-2
options snd-usb-usx2y index=-2
# Ubuntu #62691, enable MPU for snd-cmipci
options snd-cmipci mpu_port=0x330 fm_port=0x388
# Keep snd-pcsp from being loaded as first soundcard
options snd-pcsp index=-2
# Keep snd-usb-audio from beeing loaded as first soundcard
options snd-usb-audio index=-2
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
```

[Pulse Audio Volume Control settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/784te.png)

[Sound settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjfm0.png)