# Ubuntu 22.04 sound not working on new install

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 22.04, alsa

I have no sound after a fresh install of 22.04 on https://amzn.eu/d/1erCTeT

At first I had "dummy input" only and the sound card was not detected

I have updated the kernel to latest with using mainline and upgraded/updated apt

I have tried
[ubuntu 22.04 audio output not working (dummy audio)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406646/ubuntu-22-04-audio-output-not-working-dummy-audio)
to add the line `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

and

[Sound card not detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - sof-audio-pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci) to change the `/etc/default/grub` lines to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="intel_iommu=on,igfx_off"
```

this has allowed something to be detected:

```
~$ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: Generic Digital [Generic Digital]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

and `alsamixer` shows this

[image]

pulseaudio now shows "Built-in Audio Digital Sterio (HDMI)" as the only output device but still no sound from speakers or headphones

Edit:

Some more information:

```
~$ lspci -v | grep -A6 Audio
00:0e.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Celeron N3350/Pentium N4200/Atom E3900 Series Audio Cluster (rev 0b)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Sound
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at 91218000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 91000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
```