# No HFP audio after upgrade from 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio

since I upgraded to 22.04 I haven't been able to configure bluetooth speakers as microphone+speaker for video calls and other.

I can use them as hi-fi speakers, but when I try to configure them as *"Freehand unit (HFP)"* audio becomes crackling and noisy (not sure if in English this option is also named *Freehand unit*).

I have tryied some [solutions related to pulseaudio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1428745/ubuntu-22-04-sound-not-working-on-new-install) and [also this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1423121/no-sound-in-ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-after-upgrading-from-20-04-lts) but non of them worked.

This [other solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704573/sound-crackling-ubuntu-22-04) seems to complex for me and I didn't try.

My devices are detected, they work as hi-fi play, but not as microphone+speaker. In other laptops or mobile and can use them properly.

Comment: With the update GUI utility that popus on Gnome

Comment: My current version is Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, in my previous version, also an LTS (I believe 20.04) I was prompted with the upgrade notice quite often, until I finally pushed the button "Upgrade" (I improved the title of this question, I sayed Ubuntu 20, it's 20.04)

Comment: Oh, and in 20.04 I think it was Unity, not Gnome. Now in 22.04 it's Gnome.

Comment: It was Gnome in 20.04 Unity is an installer app.