# built-in audio doesn't work - microphone, speakers one of them is not working - Del G3 3590 with Ubuntu 22.04, 22.10, 23.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, dell, microphone, speakers

Built-in audio is not working in laptop Dell G3 3590 with Ubuntu 22.04, Ubuntu 22.10, and Ubuntu 23.04.

| Audio I/O | Results |
| --- | --- |
| Microphone - Built-in Audio | dosn’t work if built-in speakers work. |
| Speakers - Built-in Audio | dosn’t work if built-in microphone works. |
| Headset Microphone | Working |
| Headset Speaker | Working |

Here are the ***observations with config changes***

i) blacklist snd-hda-intel
blacklist snd-soc-skl
With the above config at at /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf, built-in mic is fine, Internal speakers are not working.

ii) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash snd_hda_intel.dmic_detect=0" or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=1"
With the above config at grub, built in mic not working, built in speakers are fine.

iii) GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash" or
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quite splash snd_intel_dspcfg.dsp_driver=3"
With the above configs  at grub, built-in mic is fine, Internal speakers are not working.

https://github.com/thesofproject/linux/issues/1877#issuecomment-596600017
[Sound card not detected - Ubuntu 20.04 - sof-audio-pci](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1243369/sound-card-not-detected-ubuntu-20-04-sof-audio-pci)

***System info***

alsa-info http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=306c16560f8211df12a74df3d8443f5101ff6738
firmware-sof-signed is already the newest version (2.2.4-1).
libasound2 is already the newest version (1.2.8-1build1).
/usr/share/alsa/ucm - no files
/usr/share/alsa/ucm2 - have files

How to make both built in microphone and speaker working?

thanks