# Static Sound Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: sound, 22.04, hda-intel

I just got a refurbished HP EliteDesk 800 G3. Running Ubuntu 22.04.3, there is a lot of static and choppiness in the sound. It comes and goes. The sound will be perfect then randomly or after suspending the system, it will be terrible. Nothing I have tried has had an immediate effect (kill pulsaudio, turn off powersave on sound card,etc). The sound card is HDA Intel PCH.
There are threads on this problem but it does not seem to be solved anywhere.

Thank you.

update: I also tried installing latest SOF binaries as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/142531). It did not work. I am about ready to give up, return this computer and get another. I see this problem as some obscure thing with HP EliteDesk 800 G3 running Linux. If anyone has insight, please let us know.

Comment: I had a sub-woofer that would do that, and it was in the wiring connecting the volume and bass to the speaker. If it is software related, I would not know.

Comment: How is the audio driver, did you check that?

Comment: This is probably a HP problem. It is a common problem according to my online search "HP EliteDesk 800 G3 crackling sound". If you are using a bluetooth device, that driver could be the problem. I don't think this is a Ubuntu issue. HP has diagnostic tools that may find the problem.

Comment: I think this is what I need to do https://askubuntu.com/a/1424600/142531. I downloaded the repository but I do not understand the second part of the instructions here: https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin#install-process-with-installsh. The part that says: 
sudo mv /lib/firmware/intel/sof* some_backup_location/
sudo mv /usr/local/bin/sof-*     some_backup_location/ # optional
sudo ./install.sh v2.2.x/v2.2 
I am not allowed to comment on those posts so if anyone can please explain how to do that step. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks Nisnabe. Good idea for editing the question. Yes I saw the links. The first link only had solutions for windows. The second link said this is a problem for this computer line using Linux and gave a solution which I tried and it did not work. I think I am just going to return this computer and get a different one that does not have this obscure problem.